# Animating an element from the edge of the screen to the center

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a dialog box in WPF that I'd like to enter from the edge of the screen and animate to the center when it is shown.  The dialog will need to stay positioned in the center of the screen even when the window is resized.  This seems like it should be dead-simple to do in WPF, and yet I still haven't thought up a reliable way of accomplishing this effect.  I'd prefer to use a pure "layout" approach as opposed to calculating the dialog's position using a binding.

In HTML/CSS, I would simply animate the dialog's `left` CSS property from `0`' to `50%`... is there a similar way to accomplish this effect in WPF?

Comment: Have you looked at Blend at all? Its free and can story board this in like 10sec

Comment: Just animate the `Windows` `Left` property using a `Trigger` on the `Loaded` event

Comment: @sa_ddam213 The dialog isn't an actual `Window`, it's just a `UserControl` that I'm displaying from within my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the effect, I wrote my own `Panel` subclass that acts like `Canvas` but accepts percentage offsets instead of absolute offsets.  This allowed me to animate a "modal" `UserControl` from 0% to 50% of the screen.

[Here's the class on Github.](https://github.com/nfriend/toolbox/blob/master/PercentagePanel.cs)

Usage is similar to `Canvas`:

```
<Window>
    <local:PercentagePanel>
        <Button local:PercentagePanel.Left=".10" local:PercentagePanel.Bottom=".5"
         Width="100" Height="40">Hello world!</Button>
    </local:PercentagePanel>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image: Example of PercentagePanel]

By default, the `PercentagePanel` positions its children based on the appropriate edge of each child (similar to CSS positioning).  The `PercentagePanel` can also position its children relative to each child's center via the `PositioningMode` property:

```
<local:PercentagePanel PositioningMode="Center">
```

Here's the result of changing the `PositioningMode` property in the above example:

[image: Example of PercentagePanel with PositioningMode="Center"]